# Report from text file - python

Tags: regex, python-2.7, text

I have a few files that I need to extract certain information from:
Example of the content of file (not that I've masked the IPs). Each file can be about 15K lines, example content below:

```
(*, 224.0.0.50/32), uptime: 27w6d, igmp ip pim                    
  Incoming interface: Ethernet1/36, RPF nbr: 1.1.1.2, uptime: 1w4d
  Outgoing interface list: (count: 3)                             
    Ethernet1/47, uptime: 1w5d, pim                               
    Vlan25, uptime: 7w4d, igmp                                    
    Vlan20, uptime: 27w6d, igmp                                   

(1.1.1.1/32, 224.0.0.50/32), uptime: 09:51:59, ip mrib pim             
  Incoming interface: Ethernet1/36, RPF nbr: 1.1.1.2, uptime: 09:51:59
  Outgoing interface list: (count: 3)                                 
    Ethernet1/47, uptime: 09:51:59, pim                               
    Vlan20, uptime: 09:51:59, mrib                                    
    Vlan25, uptime: 09:51:59, mrib
```

What I need to do is run through the files and print following:

```
Source IP  Group IP     Incoming Interface     Outgoing Interface
1.1.1.1    224.0.0.50    Ethernet1/36           Vlan20, Vlan25
```

What I wrote is this:

```
import re

mroute = open("multicast.txt", 'r')

for line in mroute:
    if re.match("(.*)(\()1(.*)", line):
        print line
for line in mroute:
    if re.match("(.*)(In)(.*)",line):
       print line
for line in mroute:
    if re.match("(^)(Out)(.*)",line):
       print line
```

However each section works independent when i join them it do not show anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is each of your `for line in mroute` exhausts the iterator.  A better approach would be to gather groups of lines and process them as you go.

Here is what I would start with

```
import sys, re

class Details(dict):
    _format = '%(source)-20s %(group)-20s %(incoming)-20s %(outgoing)-20s'
    header  = _format % {
        'source':'Source IP',
        'group': 'Group IP',
        'incoming': 'Incoming Interface',
        'outgoing': 'Outgoing Interface'
    }
    def __repr__(self):
        return self._format % self

    def __init__(self, g):
        super(Details, self).__init__()
        self.g = g
        self.parse_line(0, "^[(](?P<source>[^,]+), (?P<group>[^)]+)")
        self.parse_line(1, "^  Incoming interface: (?P<incoming>[^,]+),")
        self.parse_line(2, "^  Outgoing interface list: (?P<unused>.+)")
        for l in self.g[3:]:
            p = "^    ([^,]+),"
            m = re.search(p, l)
            if m:
                o = self.get('outgoing','')
                if o: o += ', '
                self['outgoing'] = o + m.group(1)

    def parse_line(self, n, p, u='?'):
        r = re.compile(p)
        e = {x:u for x in r.groupindex}
        m = r.search(self.g[n])
        d = m.groupdict() if m else e
        self.update(d)

    @staticmethod
    def parse(lines):
        groups = [[]]
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith("("):
                groups.append([])
            groups[-1].append(line)
        return [Details(g) for g in groups if g]

print Details.header
for d in Details.parse(file(sys.argv[1])):
    print d
```

Sample run

```
Source IP            Group IP             Incoming Interface   Outgoing Interface  
*                    224.0.0.50/32        Ethernet1/36         Ethernet1/47, Vlan25, Vlan20
1.1.1.1/32           224.0.0.50/32        Ethernet1/36         Ethernet1/47, Vlan20, Vlan25
```

This doesn't handle irregular data or the semantics of the interfaces
but those are easily added if you know what you want.

Comment: This is great, however seems this is way over my head, and my apology for this. How i can add my files to this...?
Also i am getting some sort of error code IndexError: List index out of range when "dry run" code you posted in this line: for d in Details.parse(file(sys.argv[1])):
Thank you and this is amazing...

Comment: I ran it as `$ python test.py sample` where `test.py` contains the program and `sample` contains the sample data.

Comment: Thanks again, apology you have to deal with so novice as myself.  
So that worked, it get me to the middle of the file and then it return following error code:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Gargolek\Multicast_FILE\Multicast_v4.py", line 47, in <module>
    print d
  File "C:\Users\Gargolek\Multicast_FILE\Multicast_v4.py", line 13, in __repr__
    return self._format % self
KeyError: 'outgoing'

Comment: Sounds like some of your data may differ from the sample.  You may want to add `self['outgoing']=""` to `__init__` before the parsing to give it a default value.